# How to update the textblock through NewFile menu click command

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to the MVVM pattern. I am facing problem in updating the textblock.I have one textblock and menu button.

```
//View.xaml for textblock

<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MenuHandler}}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="5,0,5,0" >                                   
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StatusText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="StatusText" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100" IsEnabled="True" Height="23"/>                
</Grid>

 //View.xaml for Menu 

<Menu DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MenuHandler}}" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Visible" Background="AliceBlue">    
  <MenuItem Header="_New" Command="{Binding NewFileCommand}" Name="NewFile"  >
       <MenuItem.Icon>
           <Image Source="/WhitelistBlacklistEditor;component/Images/NewFile.png"  Width="25"/>
       </MenuItem.Icon>
  </MenuItem>
</Menu >
```

In view model i am using MenuHandler class

//MenuHandler.cs

```
public string StatusText
{
    get { return _StatusText; }
    set
    {
       _StatusText = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent(StatusText);
     }
}

public ICommand NewFileCommand
{
    get { return new DelegateCommand(NewFile_Click); }
}

public void NewFile_Click()
{
    StatusText = "checking";
}
```

If i update the StatusText in other than NewFile_Click() method, the value is updating in the textblock but if i do the same in NewFile_Click() through ICommand it is not updating.
I am also inheritted the MenuHandler class by INotifyPropertyChanged and i checked by adding twoway mode in xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
```

{

private readonly Predicate _canExecute;
private readonly Action _execute;

```
public event Event Handler CanExecuteChanged;

public Delegate Command(Action<object> execute) 
               : this(execute, null)
{
}

public Delegate Command(Action<object> execute, 
               Predicate<object> canExecute)
{
    _execute = execute;
    _canExecute = canExecute;
}

public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    if (_canExecute == null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return _canExecute(parameter);
}

public override void Execute(object parameter)
{
    _execute(parameter);
}

public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    if( CanExecuteChanged != null )
    {
        CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

}

```
private DelegateCommand _NewFileCommand;
    public ICommand NewFileCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (adcom == null)
                adcom = new DelegateCommand(CommandExecuter, CommandExecute);
            return adcom;
        }

    }

    private bool CommandExecuter(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
    private void CommandExecute(object obj)
    {
            Statuscheck="";
    }
```

Comment: thaks for your reply. but i dont want declare in CommandExecute(), beacuse i have to handle many other commands like SAVE,SAVEAS,CLOSE...